# Any practical coding dojo/kata ideas?

Tags: scala

I've been asked to run a workshop and coding dojo soon for people to try out Scala and try to build something with it. The attendees are all going to be new to Scala, and could come from any of a number of languages (I'm presuming they can code in at least one mainstream language - I'm including syntax comparisons with Java, C#, Python and Ruby).

Part of the appeal of Scala is that it's practical - you can use it as a drop-in "power Java" (Java with less syntactical clutter, closures, immutability, FP, traits, singleton objects, nifty XML handling, type inference etc.) that still runs on the JVM (and on the .NET CLR supposedly) and doesn't require you to change build tools, server infrastructure, libraries, IDEs and so on. Most of the katas I've seen have been fun but not 'real world' - mathematical challenges like Project Euler and so on. These don't seem appropriate as we're trying to explore the use of it as a practical, real world language that people could consider using for both hacking and work, and because people aren't necessarily going to be too familiar with either the deeper parts of the Scala syntax or necessarily of the concepts behind functional programming.

So, has anyone come across any more practical, everyday katas rather than arithmetical 'problem solving' ones? Katas, that is, that can test whether the language, libraries and tools can satisfy the use cases of the actual day-to-day programming most people have to do rather than testing out. (Not that the impractical ones aren't fun, but just not appropriate for the kind of thing I've been asked to run.)

If I can't find good examples, I'm thinking that it might be useful to try and build something like a library catalogue - the event is for programmers who primarily work on building infrastructure for universities (and in education and culture - museums, galleries, schools, libraries and so on). It's a bit boring though, but it's the sort of thing that the attendees work on in their day-to-day existence. Any suggestions?

Comment: Probably ought to be community wiki -- there's unlikely to be a "correct" answer.  This seems more like a seed to discussion.

Comment: Okay, I've set it to community wiki

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a creative commons licensed introductory training course with hands-on exercises here:

http://github.com/javaBin/scala-training-slides

http://github.com/javaBin/scala-training-code

The slides are in Open Office format. If you don't have this installed, you can upload them to SlideShare, which will convert them for online viewing.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the programming examples in my [blog](http://dcsobral.blogspot.com) are, effectively, coding dojo exercises. Particularly the [matrices series](http://dcsobral.blogspot.com/search/label/matrix), but also the [puzzles](http://dcsobral.blogspot.com/search/label/puzzle) and [99 beers](http://dcsobral.blogspot.com/2009/10/99-beers.html). Now, don't disregard the matrices series as being "mathematical", because the problems I concern myself in it are related to the construction of classes in Scala, not to doing fancy algorithms. In fact, I pretty much skip over the mathematical algorithms themselves.

Now, [99 Scala Problems](http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/) and pretty much everything from [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) are nice exercises for the functional part of Scala, but I understand that not to be your emphasis. I do recommend [retronym](https://stackoverflow.com/users/160378/retronym)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118578/any-practical-coding-dojo-kata-ideas/2118645#2118645). [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/), not being functionally oriented, might have more general examples. There are many with [Scala examples](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Scala), of course, though you may wish to consider other tasks as well, for ideas.

There's lot of cool things to learn about Scala, but one has to be careful at beginner level. For instance, I would not speak of dependency injection (self types and the cake pattern) or of type classes (the pattern that simulates such with implicits).

Do look as well at the material on the [Scala Lang](http://www.scala-lang.org/) site, particularly the [Scala by Example](http://www.scala-lang.org/sites/default/files/linuxsoft_archives/docu/files/ScalaByExample.pdf) document.

**EDIT**

I have now overseen several Scala dojos, so here's a bit of stuff I've learned from then:

- Problems: they have to be fun, not-quite-easy, not-that-hard, and that has to be *everyone's* opinion.

  We use the [Dojo Puzzles](http://dojopuzzles.com/) site, which is in Portuguese so it won't be of use for most people here. If there's a similar site in English, I'd love to hear about it.

  The way it works is you ask for a random problem, look it over and discuss to see if you'll pick it up or not, and then indicate by saying you'll use it, you'll not use it, or maybe you'll use it but you'd like to see another one. This vote gets registered and you can see how many people picked up a problem, which helps deciding whether to pick it up or not in first place.
- Scala knowledge: it turns out it's not that important to introduce key concepts of Scala language beforehand, particularly if some of the participants have basic knowledge.

  In my experience, setting up the testing environment with a trivial "pass" test and explaining how people should write the tests is often enough to get people started. If you feel someone is struggling to write something, give a quick explanation and get on with it.
- Teaching Scala: if you do set out to teach Scala, keep lessons short and follow up with a dojo. In this case, keep a set of dojo problems that are adequate to the lesson, and, depending on how many lessons you want in one day, short.

  It helps imposing artificial constraints on how one must solve a problem. Some examples of constraints I have put in practice are no classes and single-expression methods (that is, no multiple statements or `val`/`var` declarations). The point of these constraints is making it impossible for people to solve the problem in the way they are used to, which gets them to explore the language in search of alternatives.

I have the final results of three dojos done at my current job [in this repository](https://github.com/ebc/dojo).

At the moment we are using the [Randori Kata](http://codingdojo.org/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?back=RandoriKata) format, but without fixed time or break, and with retrospective at the end of the dojo, not at the beginning of the next. This, however, is just were we are currently at -- we have experimented many variations, and we are still evolving.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could have a look at the [Ruby Quiz](http://www.rubyquiz.com/) material for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Scala by example](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaByExample.pdf) from Martin Odersky (creator of scala)